# How to share cookie between IronPython and asp.net mvc in the same website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, ironpython

I got a very old website code, and it use IronPython in asp.net mvc. I found that when I call an ajax reques through IronPython Controller after an ajax request through asp.net mvc Controller witch set some cookie, the request in IronPython Controller dose not take the cookie.
So, is there some ways to share cookie between IronPython and asp.net mvc?
Can someone help me ?

Comment: This seems to be a very specific scenario and needs more info. Could you expand your question to include more info how ironpython is used in this context and what exactly you are expecting/missing?

Comment: Have you tried checking out the docs? A google search yield the following: https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html